# How do I use a custom domain I have purchased on Go Daddy with Hotmail

Tags: email

I have just purchased a domain, e.g. www.example.com

I have also purchase a mailbox with my domain, e.g. george@example.com

I have a Hotmail (or Outlook.com as it's now known) email account that I have used for years, e.g. george@hotmail.com

I still want to use Hotmail for managing emails, however I now want people to be able to email george@example.com (instead of george@hotmail.com). I also want it so that when when I reply to emails, it shows that the email has been sent from george@example.com (not george@hotmail.com)

Can this be done?

Comment: Outlook.com and Office 365 mailboxes have almost identical user interfaces. I have an Office 365 Business Premium subscription that I use for a side business. It lets me use my own domain (the registrar doesn't need to be GoDaddy if you go this route) for my hosted Exchange mailbox, includes 2 TB of OneDrive for Business storage, as well as five installs of the Office suite for PCs and/or Mac. I like the convenience of having my Office licenses in the same place, the large amount of storage but most of all: how smoothly the custom email domain side of things works!

Answer (score 0):

This is technically possible, but the mail provider must be configured to *recognize* your domain. Some providers will map it to your existing mailbox, others will let you manage fully separate mailboxes.

Specifically at Hotmail/Outlook.com, custom domains are only available [if you are an Office 365 subscriber](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-a-personalized-email-address-in-office-365-75416a58-b225-4c02-8c07-8979403b427b). (See the linked article for instructions.) It is not available for free Hotmail accounts.

---

(Also, oddly, the way Outlook.com implements this feature means it *only* works with GoDaddy as your registrar. I suppose this is because they're using a special protocol to automatically update MX, SPF, and DKIM records in your domain. Most other providers simply tell you to add all records manually, so they don't have such limitations.)